# Javascript Compare two arrays with different sizes and return array of serial numbers of elements from first array

Tags: javascript, arrays, compare

Compare two arrays with different sizes and return array of serial numbers of elements from first array, that are the similar to those  in the second array

Example:

```
   arr1 [1,2,3,4,5,8,11,16,19]  
   arr2 [90,54,34,12,1,2,3,4,5,7,82]
```

Must return:

```
 arr3 [0,1,2,3,4]
```

Comment: And your tried codes are ?

Comment: please add why zero appears in the result set.

Comment: You do not have `0` in either if array

Comment: `let arr3 = arr1.filter(function(n){
                    return arr2.indexOf(n) >= 0;
                });`
But this code returns only similar values.

Comment: I need the array of serial numbers of those element, that are the same in both arrays.
You see, If I have `arr1 [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]` and `arr2 [23,45,67,76,2,4,6]` code must return `arr3 [1,3,5]`

Comment: what is a serial number?

Comment: it is a number of an element in the array. Example `arr [1,2,3]`
`arr[0] =1`, where 0 is serial number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and check if the element is in the first array and return then the position.

```js
function getCommon(a1, a2) {
    return a2.reduce(function (r, a) {
        var p = a1.indexOf(a);
        return p !== -1 ? r.concat(p) : r; 
    }, []);
}
console.log(getCommon([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 8, 11, 16, 19], [90, 54, 34, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 82]));
console.log(getCommon([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], [23, 45, 67, 76, 2, 4, 6]));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

ES6

```js
const getCommon = (a, b) => b.reduce((r, c) => r.concat(a.indexOf(c) + 1 ? a.indexOf(c) : []), []);

console.log(getCommon([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 8, 11, 16, 19], [90, 54, 34, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 82]));
console.log(getCommon([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], [23, 45, 67, 76, 2, 4, 6]));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Yes, that is very helpful, thanks a lot!